# How can I embed an HTTPS-link in my Fastreport PDF Export

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I use Fastreport 5 with Delphi Berlin 10.1 and created a Report, which I want to export as PDF by its Export function. In the Report are https lines, which I would like embed them with the URL, so that when I click on them, they should be opened in a WebBrowser in Windows. Is there a way that these http-sencences can be embedded with the URLs?

Comment: Almost all report objects have a hyperlink property, set it's `value` or `expression` property as you would expect.

Comment: @Brian I will check that. Thanks